# Update state with if on Quil

Tags: clojure, processing, quil

I am trying to make `10 PRINT` code with Quil. I try to transform this code from the twitter post https://twitter.com/ACharLuk/status/913094845505445890 which is using luna

[image]

This is my code for it

```
(ns tenprint.core
  (:require [quil.core :as q]
            [quil.middleware :as m]))

(defn setup []
  (q/frame-rate 30)
  (q/color-mode :hsb)
  {:x 0
   :y 0
   :scale 20
   }
  )

(defn update-state [state]

  (let [x (:x state) y (:y state) s (:scale state)]
    {
     :x (do (+ x s) ((if (>= x q/width) 0)))
     :y (do (if (>= x q/width) (+ y s)) (if (>= x q/height) (+ y s)))
     :scale (+ s 0)
     }
    )
  )

(defn draw-state [state]
  (q/background 0)

  (q/stroke 255)

  ;(q/line 0 10 10 0)

  (let [x (:x state) y (:y state) s (:scale state)]
    (if (> (rand) 0.5)
      (q/line x y (+ x s) (+ y s))
      (q/line x (+ y s) (+ x s) y)
      )
    )
  )

(q/defsketch tenprint
             :title "10PRINT"
             :size [500 500]
             :setup setup
             :update update-state
             :draw draw-state
             :settings #(q/smooth 2)
             :features [:keep-on-top]
             :middleware [m/fun-mode]
             )
```

And it just appears like this. I was trying to split the update of states, but it says that you must not have duplicated variables to be updated

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Great example project! You should consider submitting a screenshot or link to https://twitter.com/hashtag/10print

Comment: @JeremyDouglass : I did, but I forgot to hashtag :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is in the right direction and you managed to draw the first line. It  crashed when `update-state` was called. To fix the code I did the following things:

- Clojure works with pure functions where you cannot "set" values as you seem to wanted to do in `update-state` (with [`do`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/do) only the last expression is returned, not two values). To [`update-state`](https://github.com/quil/quil/wiki/Functional-mode-%28fun-mode%29) you need to return a whole new state.
- `q/height` and `q/widths` are functions that return the height and width, so call them (surround them by parentheses) to get the number out.
- When you redraw the background in `update-state` the older lines are gone, so put `(q/background 0)` in `setup`.

  - Move `(q/no-loop)` from `update-state` to the `draw-state` entry-point of the program.

And stylistically I changed this:

- Use [associative destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring#_associative_destructuring) in function parameter instead of  getting values of keys in `let`.
- Place trailing parentheses on the same line (see [Clojure style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#gather-trailing-parens)).

Below the working version:

```
(ns tenprint.core
  (:require [quil.core :as q]
            [quil.middleware :as m]))

(defn setup []
  (q/background 0) ; move setting background to setup, otherwise the state is overwritten
  (q/frame-rate 30)
  (q/stroke 255)
  (q/color-mode :hsb)
  {:x 0
   :y 0
   :scale 20})

(defn update-state [{:keys [x y scale] :as state}] ; destructure
  ;; height and width are functions you need to `(call)` to get the value
  {:x (if (>= x (q/width)) 0 (+ x scale)) ; fix if-statements
   :y (if (>= x (q/width)) (+ y scale) y) ; 'do' does something different than you think
   :scale scale}) ; no need to add 0

(defn draw-state [{:keys [x y scale] :as state}] ; destructure
  (if (>= y (q/height))
    (q/no-loop)
    (if (> (rand) 0.5)
      (q/line x y (+ x scale) (+ y scale))
      (q/line x (+ y scale) (+ x scale) y))))      

(q/defsketch tenprint
  :title "10 PRINT"
  :size [500 500]
  :setup setup
  :draw draw-state
  :update update-state
  :features [:keep-on-top]
  :middleware [m/fun-mode])
```

[image: 10PRINT]

Comment: wow. thank you for the amazing reply.. I learned more than I think.. It works! I am trying to understand the flow with functional language that I need to practice more. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks. Good luck!

Comment: Very nice! It is too bad that this doesn't run as-is on Quil.info http://quil.info/sketches/create -- I wonder what it would take to adapt it and post it to the gallery?

Comment: @JeremyDouglass Thanks. You need to add `:host "host"` in `defsketch`, then it works.

Comment: Sadly, no. Evaluated with warnings: "Use of undeclared Var tenprint.core/tenprint" ... but I don't want to turn these comments into a separate question!

Comment: @JeremyDouglass keep the default `ns` form provided by [quil.info/sketches/create](http://quil.info/sketches/create).